# Installing Lubuntu 16.10 with Encrytion

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, encryption, lvm

As some of you may know, there is bug in the installer of Lubuntu regarding full disk encryption with LVM. I have read at multiple places to use

```
sudo swapoff --all
```

as a workaround. That does not work for me, instead of the common error message I get the following:

Autopartitioning using LVM failed because an error occurred while creating the volume group. Check `/var/log/syslog` or see virtual console 4 for the details.

So here is a part of `/var/log/syslog` that I find relevant for my problem:

```
Nov  4 08:28:21 lubuntu ubiquity: /bin/autopartition-crypto: 292: /bin/autopartition-crypto: pvs: not found  
Nov  4 08:28:21 lubuntu ubiquity: /var/lib/partman/devices/=dev=sda  
Nov  4 08:28:21 lubuntu kernel: [  104.080652]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3  
Nov  4 08:28:21 lubuntu ubiquity: /bin/autopartition-crypto: 292:   /bin/autopartition-crypto: pvs: not found  
Nov  4 08:28:21 lubuntu kernel: [  104.555330]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3  
Nov  4 08:28:22 lubuntu partman: mke2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)  
Nov  4 08:28:22 lubuntu partman-crypto: kernel entropy_avail: 977 bits  
Nov  4 08:28:22 lubuntu kernel: [  104.887497] NET: Registered protocol family 38  
Nov  4 08:28:29 lubuntu ubiquity: stat: cannot stat '/dev/lubuntu-vg'  
Nov  4 08:28:29 lubuntu ubiquity: : No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what is wrong, there seems to be some program missing. I am also going to try an installation off of the alternate installer. Can you please give my some suggestions how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 13):

It's an installer bug.

Choose the "Try Lubuntu" option from the boot menu so that you get a working desktop.

Choose "start menu" -> "system tools" -> "LXTerminal"

At the console prompt, type:

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2
```

Then run the installer icon from the desktop ("Install Lubuntu 16.10").

Clearly no-one tested any installation method that uses lvm.

Comment: Thanks for this.  At this point, I'm inclined to just use the standard Ubuntu installer, which I'm sure is much more road-tested, and install LXDE as a last step.  Is there any significant difference to the end product?

Comment: "An error occurred while configuring encrypted volumes. The configuration has been aborted." I did all the steps, including swapoff. Lubuntu 17.04, that should be installed on VMware12.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems to be a version related bug. Using the common 16.04. Lubuntu installer is working.