# Problems with Lubuntu 16.xx installation - LVM with encryption

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, encryption

I am trying to install Lubuntu on an older Laptop, but I have some problems. I made a LiveUsb and boot with "Try Lubuntu first". I then start the installation with the desktop button. Later I choose the encrypted + lmv installation.

This is where I get the first error message, which is exactly the same as described in [Unsafe swap space detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393418/unsafe-swap-space-detected). So I put

```
sudo swapoff --all
```

and try again. Now I get the same  [Installing Lubuntu 16.10 with Encrytion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845401/installing-lubuntu-16-10-with-encrytion) and write

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2
```

into the console. But this does not change anything.

If I try to install it without encryption and lvm I get Ubipartman crashed and I have to shut the installation program.

I have tried the Lubuntu 16.10 and 16.04 installer, but I get the same results in both cases.

I am quite new to Linux and do not know how to proceed.
Any help would be really apreciated.

Comment: Do I understand that correctly? The installer crashes when you don't select LVM as the installation option? What option exactly did you choose there?

Comment: Yes, I chose erase disk and install lubuntu, and after it did not work with encryption+lmv, I tried without those. This was where the ubi-partman crashed.

Comment: Could you try manual partitioning please – just to see if that works at all (not to suggest that you shouldn't use LVM)? Sometimes that reveals things like the partitioning tool not finding any suitable devices. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation.

Comment: By manual partitioning you mean to select "Do something else" in the option screen? If so, I tried, and it crushed, too. I have used now the method in sudodus answer, without encryption and without lvm and this worked well. As far as I understood, I will not need lvm, if I only have one partition on this laptop, do I?

Comment: I got the same problem like you. If you found a solution, please tell me. If you didn't, I hope this question will get attention, because I'm not allowed to open another question for the same topic with the exact same problem.

Comment: Since I wanted to use this laptop only at home I decided to install it without encryption or lmv. For me the alternate installer worked perfectly. You can find it here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO  Then to install it you can follow this guide : http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/351/builds/135943/testcases/1437/results

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that the download was good with ***md5sum***?

I would recommend that you try Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, and not only 16.10, because 16.04.1 has long time support for 3 years (until April 2019) while 16.10 has only 9 months support. 16.04.1 LTS, the first point release, is debugged and polished, much better than the original 16.04 LTS version.

Try Lubuntu's ***alternate iso file*** with the text mode installer! It does not use zram and does not suffer from the problem with swap. Installing with LVM  and encrypted disk was tested during the development cycle (by me; the testcase with both encrypted disk and encrypted home inside the encrypted disk), and works also in very old computers.

You can use the following link with instructions to perform an installation with encrypted disk. The name of the testcase is slightly confusing, but it helps you do what you want:

[Alternate Install (Unencrypted home) in Lubuntu Alternate i386 in Xenial Daily (archived)](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/363/builds/126343/testcases/1660/results)

Comment: md5sum was ok. The link you sent is for the Unencrypted disk. Is it actually recommendable to encrypt the disk of an older laptop, which I want to use only at home?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that you wrote Unencrypted HOME. I  try to install it with the instructions then!

Comment: Q: Is it actually recommendable to encrypt the disk of an older laptop, which I want to use only at home? A: No, but possible. Backup is much more important.

Comment: I made the installation now with the steps in your link. All worked fine except, that after the reboot of step 28, it entered emergency mode and I could not do anything and had to hard reboot. But now it seems to work normally, so thank you very much :)

Comment: And one more question: Why is it not recommendable to encrypt the disk?

Comment: If you travel with the computer and have valuable data, it is important to encrypt the disk. But you wrote that you will only use it at home. Encryption makes it much harder to recover data (read 'impossible') if you forget the password or if the file system or the internal drive is damaged.

Comment: Ok, and what about performance? I read that it can effect low powered computers, but to which amount? And if I wanted to install it again without encryption, I would have to do the same steps as in your link except in step 16, where I could chose only lvm, right?

Comment: It might or might not make a big difference depending on the hardware. I suggest that you test it in this particular computer (compare to a system without encryption).

Comment: The performance overhead of encryption is moderate to negligible on reasonably modern hardware because the cryptographic throughput of the CPU will dwarf the I/O throughput of the storage device on any desktop system and desktop workload built since the turn of the century. And if you have a recent top-of-the shelf system with a multi-SSD-RAID you'll also have more than enough CPU cores with hardware-accelerated cryptographic instruction set support to throw at the problem.

Comment: …also almost all computation tasks (or their phases) are either CPU-bound or I/O-bound but rarely both so it doesn't hurt much to add some CPU overhead on an I/O-bound task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar but *simpler* in order to install *without encryption*. There are also testcases, that you can use for this task, for example this one:

[Alternate Install (Entire Disk) in Lubuntu Alternate i386 in Xenial Daily](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/351/builds/135943/testcases/1437/results)