# Why do I have an issue installing Lubuntu 17.04 with encryption?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lubuntu, encryption, lvm

I was able to easily install it without encryption, but now that I'm trying to run an encrypted install I run inton the following issues:

`An unsafe swap space has been detected...` [so I opened Terminal and use `sudo swapoff --all` and restarted the installation.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393418/unsafe-swap-space-detected)

`Unexpected error while creating volume group: Autopartitioning using LVM failed because an error occurred while creating the volume group. Check /var/log/syslog or see virtual console 4 for the details`. [To fix this, I did `sudo apt-get install lvm2` and restarted the installation.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845401/installing-lubuntu-16-10-with-encrytion)

`Configuration of encrypted volumes failed: An error occurred while configuring encrypted volumes. The configuration has been aborted.` I don't know how to fix this.

The strange thing is that it installed perfectly fine unencrypted, so I'm not sure why the encryption is having so many issues.

If it matters, the reason I'm reinstalling is I accidentally misused `chown` on important system files, but that shouldn't affect reinstallation files anyway, right?

Comment: you should never, ever `chown` on important system files...

Comment: it is unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Install Lubuntu on an existing file system... installing LVM at the same time... and encrypt at the same time.  If you don't know how to fix a corrupted LVM, then why use it in the first place. If you have a running Lubuntu on an un-encrypted file system, why not encrypt from there on.  Take simple steps to keep matters under control.

Comment: @WillemK I missed the rest of the chown extension so it did a much larger core directory.

Comment: Sorry Evan, but I don't understand what you mean... chown extension? a larger core directory? Is this important to get your Lubuntu (re)installed? I suggest you decide first what you want to do first... I think a fresh install of Lubuntu on an empty (erased) partition.